# Check if there is any subdirectory in a folder and return path in c#

Tags: c#, .net

The tittle is pretty self explanatory. I want to know how could I get fullpath of a subdirectory if there's a subdirectory in a folder.

Here's what I have to check if there's any subdirectories in the folder.

```
        private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool hasSubfolders;
        string SubFolderFullPath = heyman + "/dump";
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(SubFolderFullPath);
        DirectoryInfo[] subdirs = directory.GetDirectories();

        if (subdirs.Length == 0) MessageBox.Show("Dossier dump vide...");

    }
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be good. It would help in framing an answer.

Comment: Try this: `Directory.EnumerateDirectories(System.IO.Path.Combine(heyman, "dump")).Any()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this method

```
Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
```

will return string[] of subdirectory's path. if you want to check recursively you may add more option

```
GetDirectories(targetDirectory, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

you can check if a subdirectory exist by checking its return value length (just like what you did)

[msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why check recursively? How does that help the OP?

Comment: in part `Check if there is any subdirectory in a folder ..` yes OP wont need it but with part
`..and return path in c#` i believe it is good to know